# AJAX - No Refresh , loading auto refresh to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My only problem is the page does not load auto refresh, tho it is loading when i refresh the page.. ***P.S*** Im loading the page to another page

here is my html and ajax code with its database.

> My **Trigger Button**

```php
    <?php
        $data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM announcement");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($data);
        if ($count != 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
                echo '
                    <button class="btn btn-danger nav-link delannouncement" id="delannouncement">Resume System</button>';
                $dataid = $row['id'];
            }
        }else{
            echo '<button class="btn btn-primary nav-link announcement" id="announcement">Passenger Announcement</button>';
        }
    ?>
```

> Fetching the Data in **Database**

Here is where I call the data in mysql from ajax to here.

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM announcement");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($data);
    if ($count != 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
          echo '<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="position:fixed;  display: none; padding-top: 100px; 
          left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: rgb(0,0,0); background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); ">
                <div class="container" style="width: 100%">
                <div class="card col-12" style="background-color: red; color: white;">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <p><h3 class="text-center">Announcement</h3></p>
                </div>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                      <h5>'.$row['additional_info'].'</h5>
                      <p>Please click refresh button to resume after the announcement</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                    </div>';
                  $dataid = $row['id'];
          }
      }

        ?>
        </div>

        <script>
        document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='block';
```

> My **AJAX code**
>   *This is my AJAX code, here is where I got the problem the modal will not load right after I clicked the button, before it will work, I need to refresh the page how to fix this problem*

```
 $('.announcement').on("click", function () {
        $.confirm({
            title: 'Announcement',
            content: '' +
                '<form action="" class="formName">' +
                '<div class="form-group">' +
                '<label>Announcement Info</label>' +
                '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter announcement here" class="add-info form-control" required />' +
                '</div>' +
                '</form>',
            buttons: {
                formSubmit: {
                    text: 'Submit',
                    btnClass: 'btn-blue',
                    action: function () {
                        var addInfo = this.$content.find('.add-info').val();
                            $.confirm({
                                type: 'red',
                                theme: 'material',
                                title: 'Are you sure you want to make an announcement?',
                                content:'<strong>Announcement Info:</strong> ' + addInfo,
                                buttons: {
                                    Yes: {
                                        btnClass: 'btn-green',
                                        action: function () {
                                            $.ajax({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                url: "announcement.php",
                                                data: {
                                                    addInfo: addInfo
                                                },
                                                dataType: "text",
                                                success: function (data) {
                                                    window.location.replace("change-password.php");

                                                },
                                                error: function (err) {
                                                    console.log(err);

                                                }

                                            });

                                        }

                                    },
                                    No: {
                                        text: 'No', // With spaces and symbols
                                        action: function () {
                                            $.alert('Announcement Cancelled');
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    }
                },
                cancel: function () {
                    //close
                },
            },
            onContentReady: function () {
                // bind to events
                var jc = this;
                this.$content.find('form').on('submit', function (e) {
                    // if the user submits the form by pressing enter in the field.
                    e.preventDefault();
                    jc.$$formSubmit.trigger('click'); // reference the button and click it
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

I am new to ajax coding and syntax help me to finish this project please.

Answer (score 0):

Do not get into this much complex solution, just return data in json(or xml) format form your API, and then render whatever html you want on frontend(i.e. do not return html form Backend)

Comment: Do you have any solution to this?

Comment: You can generate json like this in php https://www.w3schools.com/js/showphp.asp?filename=demo_file and then create html fron the given json on client side(you can use http://www.json2html.com/#getstarted plugin for simplicity so as to avoid string concatenation)